# Blowup along an open subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I think I heard somebody talking about the blowup of a variety $X$ along an *open* subvariety $U\subseteq X$ but I can't find anything about that on the internet. Was this just a misunderstanding or is there really something like *the blowup of a scheme along an open subscheme*? What does it mean then and where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood something. In algebraic geometry, we only blowup closed subschemes. Of course, it can happen that your open subset $U$ is also closed. Then the blowup along $U$ is just the inclusion $X\setminus U \to X$.